# How to get numbers of sellers using MWS or Product Advertising API?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services

How to get the numbers of sellers in amazon using MWS or Product Advertising API?

Is there any way to get the numbers of sellers in amazon via API ?

I am using python to call API.